# Como utilizar CDI no WebService?

Tags: java, cdi

Estou tentando injetar um bean `@Injection` dentro de um `WebService`, mas o bean sempre fica nulo.

A injeção de dependências está funcionando em meu projeto. Quando uso `@Injection` dentro de um Managebean para uma página jsp tudo fica ok.

```
@WebService
public class listaUsuariosWS {
    @Inject private LoginService loginService;
    public String getName(){
        List<Usuario> lst = loginService.listarTodos();
        Usuario u = lst.get(1);
        String nome = u.getNomeUsuario();
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Alguma ideia do que poderia ser?

Comment: Poderia colocar mais informações sobre o problema? O código que está testando, talvez o stacktrace gerado

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza, o código em si é bem simples:

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza, o código em si é bem simples:   `@WebService
public class listaUsuariosWS {
 
 @Inject
 private LoginService loginService;
 
 public String getName(){
  
  List<Usuario> lst =  loginService.listarTodos();
  Usuario u = lst.get(1);
  String nome = u.getNomeUsuario();
  return nome;
  
 }

}`  O objeto loginService sempre fica null

Answer (score 0):

A classe listaUsuariosWS tem que ser gerenciada pelo contêiner para que o Bean seja injetado .
Tente dar um escopo para ela utilizando EJB:

```
@Stateless
```

ou CDI:

```
@RequestScope
```

Obs.: Não sei se o @RequestScope funciona em @WebService, só indiquei ele para exemplificar.